# Splitting line at local maxima and minima of raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, line, slope

I'd like to find those points along a polyline where a raster has local minima or maxima (find peaks and valleys where the line slope is zero).

Using ArcMap's slope tool didn't work as desired because it calculates the slope of the raster itself, not the slope of the line. This is a problem when the line goes over a hill, but doesn't touch the top: then the raster slope is non-zero, while the line slope would be zero.

How can I find peaks and valleys along a line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am hydrologist, this is why I like solution by @fatih_dur (+1 from me) however it will most likely struggle with minimums simply because hydrologic modelling starts with original DEM modification, i.e. filling the sinks. Changes can be very dramatic. As a result you might find "stream" running very far away from its' true position.

This is why I intentionally drawn line over ponding areas, upstream from roads:
[image: Inputs]

Workflow:

```
arcpy.InterpolateShape_3d("dem","LINE","C:/FELIX_DATA/SCRARCH/line3d.shp")
arcpy.FeatureVerticesToPoints_management("line3d","C:/FELIX_DATA/SCRARCH/points.shp","ALL")
arcpy.AddZInformation_3d("points","Z","NO_FILTER")
arcpy.AddField_management("points","loc_Min","SHORT")
```

Make sure your points layer is sitting on the top of the table of content and run this field calculator expression on newly created field:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
lr=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0]
tbl=[row[0] for row in arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(lr,"Z")]
lMax=len(tbl)
def getLocal(fid,z,n):
 if fid<n or fid>lMax-n-1:return -1
 subset=tbl[fid-n:fid+n+1]
 if z==min(subset):return 1
 return 0
```

## -----------------------------

```
getLocal( !FID!, !Z!,5)
```

**As one can I see I defined local minimum as lowest point for 5 neighbours before it and after it, point itself included.** Expression will return 1 for point defined that way.

OUTPUT below shows points with "loc_Min" = 1:

[image: OUTPUT]

I'll leave it to you to modify expression to find local maximums and set local extremum definition you are comfortable with.

NOTE: it is very easy thing to do in Excel, if you know how to easily export data from GIS, and import it back.

ATTENTION: expression assumes your points are stored in a shapefile, not geodatabase feature class.

Comment: The solution you suggest is a very good base, but must be taken with a grain of salt, since the extremum definition will fail for long passages with points at equal height. But I marked it as accepted since you pointed out that I need to use my own definition anyway.

Comment: What's odd: I replaced min(subset) with max(subset) to find local peaks, and the center of [49,8237 49,4548 **50,032** 49,8436 48,9803] is not marked as such.

Answer (score 3):

If you are planning to do this in ArcGIS, you will need Spatial Analyst's Hydrology toolset. Finding the peaks is termed as ridgeline identification and [this ESRI technical article](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011289) explain the process nicely or you can use [the Basin tool](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Basin/009z0000004z000000/) in the same toolset for this purpose. Valleys, or right terminology here is stream/flow lines, is an iterative process and I advise you to have a look at [Identifying Stream Networks help page](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Identifying_stream_networks/009z0000005v000000/) and start processing your data from there.