# Counting longest distance between two lines using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, distance

How do I count longest distance between two lines as shown at the picture in every bump using QGIS?

[image]

Comment: which software are you using?

Comment: I am using QGIS but i have acces to ArcGIS.

Comment: Here is a workflow, create Polygons from all lines (Feature to Polygon), Create Centroids (Feature to Point), run Near to Find the distance from Centroid Point to Line Edge, Double the near Distance.

Comment: What have you tried with QGIS?  If you wish to also ask about ArcGIS Desktop then please do so in a separate question with details about what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: ArcGis solution: convert bendy line vertices to points, use near to compute distances to simplified line. Use field calculation from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213445/splitting-line-at-local-maxima-and-minima-of-raster/213453#213453 to define 'peaks'.

Comment: If you exclude the "at every bump" criteria, what you're looking for is the "Hausdorff distance". A possible workflow would be to split the lines by each other, then for each pair of split segments calculate the Hausdorff distance.

Answer (score 3):

I see interesting suggestions I would love to try. Below is what I have tried so far.

A sample data `rivers`; I tried to mimic two rivers (*type* = `straight` and *type* = `meander`).

[image]

Then,

(1) Create a new layer of points along the `meander` river at 1 meter interval (or any interval to fit your required accuracy). I used `v.to.point` which returned a new point layer (*layer name*: `Points along lines`).

(2) Open the attribute table of `Points along lines` layer. Create a new field `dist` with an expression:

```
distance(
  closest_point(geometry(get_feature('rivers', 'type', 'straight')), $geometry), 
  $geometry
  )
```

The above expression add a new field which shows distance from each point to the straight river.

(3) Click on a point which you think the farthermost, observe corresponding distance (`dist`) value highlighted on the attribute table. (I missed the right one but it is easy to find the distance I want = `3.90036 meters`.)

[image]